# Google Drive Android API - Google Drive App

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Does Google Drive Android API need Google Drive App installed on the device to work?

I can't find any information about it, and I can't really test it without registering for the Google Developer Console...

Answer (score 2):

> Does Google Drive Android API need Google Drive App installed on the device to work?

No, the Google Drive app doesn't need to be installed. However you do use Google Play services SDK to work with Drive and that must be present for your app to work correctly. As long as you follow the documentation on [setting up](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) Google Play Services then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: thx for the answer, I'm propably going to test it then (register for the Console). To do it properly, I'm gonna accept the answer when I confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, you don't have to install it in your computer. But you must get client_id and client_secret credentials from console developer if you want to use restful api in your test operations.